# PYSPARK - Predicted Target Label MISSING one class - Logistic regression

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, logistic-regression

I have just started my Pyspark journey building a Logistic Regression model that predicts users device type (tablet, phone, tv, pad, and desktop).

I have 4 features:

1. total_minutes
2. vendor_version (iOs, Web, Android, etc)
3. day_of_week
4. time_of_day

---

**Accuracy**

The algorithm are working and I have got a good accuracy ~ 83% and when I do final checking to see my predicted target label (device_type), I can see that I am missing one class (pad).

**Prototype**

At first, I am prototyping with small data, and thought it might need more data. So I grabbed more data (1 million rows) and ran the Log Reg model.

When it comes to check the prediction target class label, I am still missing one class (pad). Does any one have encountered the same issue?

**Hypothesis**

My hypothesis at first is that, the 'pad' class label is so small (3312 rows in full data, not split into train and test just yet vs 150,000 rows of data and above for other target class labels) that Log Reg didnt even bother to predict for it.

**Question**

Could this be the case? Or is there other thing that I should check?

My colleague ran the same algorithm but in Scala but have all the target class labels in his predicted table. So I am not sure what is the issue here.

Let me know if you need more info.

Here is a sample of how the data looks like:

```
device_id   vendor_version  total_minutes   dow hour    device_type
1   TV           100                5               22          tv
2   Web           20                6               10          desktop
3   iOs            4                3               9           phone
4   Android    12030                7               15          pad
5   Chromecast  2300                2               12          tablet
6   Playstation  587                1               3           tv
```

Best,

Sugi

Comment: What do you mean that one class is missing? Can you [edit] your question and show some code + output that shows you a class is missing? Also, outline (briefly) how you are setting up your LR to be a multilabel predictor.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to print out a confusion matrix, and you can verify your hypothesis of "Class Imbalance". This problem is more related to machine learning than spark or pyspkark.

Edit:
You can find details about the confusion matrix [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix).
Also you may find this [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/mllib-evaluation-metrics.html#multiclass-classification) helpful.

Comment: Well, I didnt print out the confusion matrix. But I managed to get the probability for the different classes predicted. The last class having a really small probability for all values, 0.04 % or less. This seems to be re-inforcing my hypothesis. Although its curious that my colleague was able to get all the target class in his prediction.

Comment: I still think you should print a confusion matrix, did your colleague use the exact same log reg (package/algo/programming language) to achieve the same results? If you and your colleague are using exact same code and getting different results then its a issue with the code, if there is a difference then you have to analyse the results, and algo that you are using (package/library).